# JAX-RS 2.0 (Resteasy client) for server to server communication

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

This is a rather generic question but would you use use JAX-RS to communicate between two server services running on potentially two different hosts (leveraging the Resteasy client)?
Or would you stick to the more traditional EJB remote invocation?

I'm a bit worried about the following potential issues:
- maintaining a pool of Http connections - will be per client and not global to the application server
- no optimisation if both services are on the same host (EJB invocations would be local in this case)
- authorisation (credentials): managed by the application itself when configuring the RestClient vs. container managed for EJB
- what else?

Any feedback?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most implementations of JAX-RS have a client API, so the setup should be easy if you share annotated interfaces between the two projects. Communication may be slower than with other solutions because you have to serialize/deserialize all parameters and responses, usually in formats like XML or JSON. I wouldn't worry to much about optimizing inter-process communication as communicating with localhost is still is way faster than with a remote machine. If you expect to have parts of this API public, REST would be the best option, regardless of performance.

If the communication will only be internal, and you *really* care about performance, you could use a more specialized framework like [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). JAX-RS is a JavaEE Standard and REST are well established though, which might be more important than performance. For more large, complex, JavaEE based systems, a common solution would be to use messaging and integration frameworks like Apache ActiveMQ and Apache Camel, which also support JAX-WS/JAX-RS frameworks like Apache CXF and should have optimization for inter-process communication. For small applications this seems like overkill though.

I never used EJB so I can't really compare it to other solutions. From what I've heard, the whole EJB approach is way to complex and hasn't been adapted very well in the industry. I also would worry a bit about cross platform compatibility.

I would choose a solution that isn't too complex and easy to setup. One last thing: In my experience, when you expect two application to be running on the same machine so often that you want to optimize it, they probably should have been combined in a single server application in the first place, or maybe one of the servers should have been an optional plugin for the other one.